# Employee monitoring: periodic screenshots and/or idle time measurement

Tags: screenshot, remote-desktop

I have an employee to whom we have lended a company laptop so he can work from home.

His productivity has dropped recently.  I want to get an understanding of how often he's actually at the computer.  I suspect he is gone for 2-3 hours at a time.  I can use remote desktop to peer in, but that seems highly intrusive and many people can't work if they feel they're being watched.

Is there a software that just takes periodic screenshots, e.g. every 10 minutes?  That way if nothing moves for 3 hours it would be obvious.

Or is there some other software that can show you how long someone is "AFK" during the day?

Comment: I don't know about pre-made software, but a programmer could easily make a script that you could autostart with the laptop, which could collect statistical data for you. However, you'd have to install it on the laptop (and take measures to ensure the employee doesn't disable it) before giving it to the employee. It would be easiest for you to get the data after the employee hands the laptop back, but you could have it send it to you.

Comment: Another option is to ask the employee how often and how long they use the laptop.

Comment: Thanks, of course I can make something myself, but I think someone else has probably done it.  The employee is unfortunately not very responsive.  All queries are responded with "yes sure I'll do it now" but then nothing happens.